# Create deployable war in Grails with weceem plugin

Tags: grails, deployment, weceem

I am using GGTS 3.6.4 with Grails 2.4.5, Weceem 1.3 and Java 1.8u40.
I created a web application in Grails using the weceem plugin and everything works fine when I start the app with the command `grails run-app`.

I tried to create a deployable war from this project, but every time I install the war only an empty white page is displayed. The war does not even contain index.html etc..

Then I tried to create a new Grails project including the weceem 1.3 plugin and executing the command `grails run war`. The result was the same. I got only an empty page displayed. When I use the command `run-app` everything works fine.....

```
|Done creating WAR target\NaturlichWeb-0.1.war
|Running Grails application
Error |
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
Error |
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Xeno/Desktop/GGTS_new/grails-2.4.5/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
Error |
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Xeno/Desktop/GGTS_new/workspace/NaturlichWeb/target/work/tomcat/webapps/NaturlichWeb/WEB-INF/lib/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
Error |
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
Error |
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
Weceem: Initializing ehcache with default weceem ehcache.xml from plugin resource: class path resource [weceem-default-ehcache.xml]
Configuring Spring Security Core ...
... finished configuring Spring Security Core
2015-04-02 11:21:13,986 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table tag_links drop constraint FK_lmil1jg72pjc8ei5p6kk5g9un if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "TAG_LINKS" nicht gefunden
Table "TAG_LINKS" not found; SQL statement:
alter table tag_links drop constraint FK_lmil1jg72pjc8ei5p6kk5g9un if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_role drop constraint FK_it77eq964jhfqtu54081ebtio if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "USER_ROLE" nicht gefunden
Table "USER_ROLE" not found; SQL statement:
alter table user_role drop constraint FK_it77eq964jhfqtu54081ebtio if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table user_role drop constraint FK_apcc8lxk2xnug8377fatvbn04 if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "USER_ROLE" nicht gefunden
Table "USER_ROLE" not found; SQL statement:
alter table user_role drop constraint FK_apcc8lxk2xnug8377fatvbn04 if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_1i8ibd0dm67mut0hh09oqt452 if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "WCM_CONTENT" nicht gefunden
Table "WCM_CONTENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_1i8ibd0dm67mut0hh09oqt452 if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_9c59e0m1eb1xaeoy5h95xlyme if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "WCM_CONTENT" nicht gefunden
Table "WCM_CONTENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_9c59e0m1eb1xaeoy5h95xlyme if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_c9u6eo21g7eku09byvrsjjm0s if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "WCM_CONTENT" nicht gefunden
Table "WCM_CONTENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_c9u6eo21g7eku09byvrsjjm0s if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_sgkk9pe0yu0f2brjsl8j20svy if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "WCM_CONTENT" nicht gefunden
Table "WCM_CONTENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_sgkk9pe0yu0f2brjsl8j20svy if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_qs79ql67napbqpkvni2tw6ha0 if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "WCM_CONTENT" nicht gefunden
Table "WCM_CONTENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_qs79ql67napbqpkvni2tw6ha0 if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_8duair0heuk4lw83fsp2arsce if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "WCM_CONTENT" nicht gefunden
Table "WCM_CONTENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table wcm_content drop constraint FK_8duair0heuk4lw83fsp2arsce if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table wcm_related_content drop constraint FK_gunqv3de4a2aowjtox5l10ug4 if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "WCM_RELATED_CONTENT" nicht gefunden
Table "WCM_RELATED_CONTENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table wcm_related_content drop constraint FK_gunqv3de4a2aowjtox5l10ug4 if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - HHH000389: Unsuccessful: alter table wcm_related_content drop constraint FK_oxph3lt0u4eteq81gnh2dljrd if exists
2015-04-02 11:21:14,002 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Tabelle "WCM_RELATED_CONTENT" nicht gefunden
Table "WCM_RELATED_CONTENT" not found; SQL statement:
alter table wcm_related_content drop constraint FK_oxph3lt0u4eteq81gnh2dljrd if exists [42102-176]
2015-04-02 11:21:30,296 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR export.SimpleSpaceImporter  - Unable to import Weceem ZIP file C:\Users\Xeno\AppData\Local\Temp\weceem-space-import4655006495072954442.tmp
: The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/C:/Users/Xeno/Desktop/GGTS_new/grails-2.4.5/lib/org.apache.ant/ant/jars/ant-1.8.4.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml:37: Problem: failed to create task or type componentdef
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:508)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:434)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:281)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:790)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:237)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:216)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:414)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:160)
    at org.weceem.export.SimpleSpaceImporter.execute(SimpleSpaceImporter.groovy:34)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmImportExportService$_importSpace_closure1.doCall(WcmImportExportService.groovy:24)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:815)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:715)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmImportExportService.importSpace(WcmImportExportService.groovy:20)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService.importSpaceTemplate(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:430)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService$_createSpace_closure7.doCall(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:384)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:815)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:715)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService.createSpace(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:364)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService$_createDefaultSpace_closure3.doCall(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:210)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService.withPermissionsBypass(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:1606)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService.createDefaultSpace(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:209)
    at WeceemGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(WeceemGrailsPlugin.groovy:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: jar:file:/C:/Users/Xeno/Desktop/GGTS_new/grails-2.4.5/lib/org.apache.ant/ant/jars/ant-1.8.4.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml:37: Problem: failed to create task or type componentdef
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.getNotFoundException(UnknownElement.java:484)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:416)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:160)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.execute(Antlib.java:146)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:432)
    ... 25 more
--- Nested Exception ---
jar:file:/C:/Users/Xeno/Desktop/GGTS_new/grails-2.4.5/lib/org.apache.ant/ant/jars/ant-1.8.4.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml:37: Problem: failed to create task or type componentdef
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.getNotFoundException(UnknownElement.java:484)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:416)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:160)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.execute(Antlib.java:146)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:432)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:281)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:790)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:260)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:237)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:216)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:414)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:160)
    at org.weceem.export.SimpleSpaceImporter.execute(SimpleSpaceImporter.groovy:34)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmImportExportService$_importSpace_closure1.doCall(WcmImportExportService.groovy:24)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:815)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:715)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmImportExportService.importSpace(WcmImportExportService.groovy:20)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService.importSpaceTemplate(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:430)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService$_createSpace_closure7.doCall(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:384)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:815)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:715)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService.createSpace(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:364)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService$_createDefaultSpace_closure3.doCall(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:210)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService.withPermissionsBypass(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:1606)
    at org.weceem.services.WcmContentRepositoryService.createDefaultSpace(WcmContentRepositoryService.groovy:209)
    at WeceemGrailsPlugin$_closure2.doCall(WeceemGrailsPlugin.groovy:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Error |
org.weceem.export.ImportException: Uploaded file can't be unpacked. Check it and try again.
Error |
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
Error |
```

Comment: Anything interesting in the log files?

Comment: The creation of the war works seamless. I have added now the exceptions that are thrown during the deployment process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the core issue:

> failed to create task or type componentdef

If you google that with your favorite search engine you'll see that a frequent cause of that is having both Ant 1.7.x and 1.8.x jars in the war file. Grails 2.4.5 uses Ant 1.8.4, but the Ant jars are scoped to not be included in the war - did you add an explicit dependency in BuildConfig.groovy?

My guess is that Weceem or one of the plugins that it depends on has an Ant 1.7 dependency. If that is the problem, you should be able to add an exclusion for Ant 1.7 once you determine which plugin is causing it to be included. Or you can use `grails.war.resources` to delete the extra jar from the staging directory before all of the files are added to the war. This is described in the docs and in [this Marc Palmer blog post](http://www.anyware.co.uk/2005/2009/01/21/excluding-files-from-a-war-with-grails-the-right-way/), and would be something like

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir ->
    delete(file:"$stagingDir/WEB-INF/lib/ant-1.7.???.jar")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to be the problem! When I run the command run-war the war is created and it is working, but when I try to deploy it on the webserver I get the error message: Failed to obtain node lock, is the following location writable?: [/etc/init.d/elasticsearch] I tried also to change the elasticsearch.path.data variable, but it doesn't change anything. Do you have maybe also an idea what could be the issue?

Comment: You can try the example of configuration for elasticsearch that is done in weceem-app, check here https://github.com/jCatalog/weceem-app/blob/master/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy (from line 171);